Is there something like "No well"?
In a movie, a woman who makes handcraft wants to give one of her works to an old professor of hers as a gift, but the man wants to pay for it to support her talent, but she insists on giving it as a present. Here is just a little part of conversation:

Woman: I made it this morning with you in mind. It's a gift.


Professor: No well.


Woman: No.


Professor: It's a gift okay, a gift graciously received. Now come give give your old Professor a hug. I'm so proud of you you Magic in Mount Holly (2021 Hallmark) (see:35:43-36:00)

Based on what I hear and verification by the subtitles(which might be wrong), the man seems to say "No well.", and right after that the woman says "No." as if he had asked a question.
I have been thinking about "No well" and looked it up, but can't find a meaning for it. And that part does not seem to make any sense.
What is it that I can't get right?

Didn't watch.  But is it possibly "Noel?" ?

It sounds to me as though he is addressing her, “Noël, …”. Is that her name? I am not going to search through the video to find out. It would certainly be on brand for a character in a Hallmark movie.

@TimR, I thought about that, but then her answering "No" wouldn't make sense.

Unless it's not a Christmas gift.

It is indeed the young woman's name.  Please try to figure out what they're saying in some better movies :-)

@TimrR, Aaaaaa yes, I now understand it is the woman's name :) Thanks. He seems to say it like "No well", and the subtitles show it that way. I never thought "Noel" could be a name for a girl.

@PaulTanenbaum, yes what you thought is right. I understood now it was her name, which I would have never imagined.

@TimR, By saying "Please try to figure out what they're saying in some better movies", do you mean the actors and acctresses are not native English speakers or do you mean the quality of the film is not good? If it is the second, I know it. I am not watching it as a quailty film, but I just try to watch anything where native english speakers speak, so I could encounter as much different speech style as I can.

The character's name is Noelle Palmer. Played by someone called Taryn Hacker.

And as to why she responded "No" - it's apparent from the man's tone of voice that when he says, "Noelle..." that he is expressing mild disapproval, referring back to his earlier point that he should be paying for the object. Her "no" is a rejection of that point.

@CanadianYankee, yeah now it makes sense why she said "NO". Thank you for the explanation.

I’m voting to close this question because it was based on a mis-hearing and misunderstanding.

He isn’t saying, “No well,” but addressing her (by name), “Noël…” or “Noelle…”
The given name Noël is, of course French for Christmas. And given the saccharine nature for which Hallmark movies are notorious, it and its variant spellings are a no-brainer choice for naming an attractive young female character.

Isn't Noël a man's name?

According to IMDb, she's "Noelle Palmer", with "Noelle" of course being the feminine way to spell it.

Not in the U.S., it isn’t, @MichaelHarvey.  Not often. Perhaps it’s an example of the pattern of names shifting from men’s-given to women’s-given. Anyway, Laurel makes the question moot.

@MichaelHarvey, consider the (female) actress Noël Wells. And for that matter, the Brit Noël Leslie, Countess of Rothes.

@PaulTanenbaum, Interestingly Merriem-Webster dictionary gives an alternative spelling to "Noel" in the form of "Nowell", which would sound to us non-native speakers completely the same as "No well", when said quickly, which is why I might have heard it that way. Here is the link:  https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nowell

Hearing it that way is perfectly normal. The two are essentially homophonic.

In the age when (in English-speaking countries at least) parents are free to call their children pretty much anything they choose, and to spell those names accordingly, it seems to me futile to declare which names are always male or female. For the record, my neighbour here in Portugal is José Maria (he's male).
